# Mix AdMob and other Ad solution in one Android app

Tags: android, admob

I'm wondering if it's not against the AdMob's policy to use it alongside with other ad solution in one Android app?

Thanks,
ToM

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting adMob's Terms of Service.

Comment: Have you read the policies? What do they tell you?

Comment: This is not related to programming.

Comment: Also, please select my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's against. Don't do this, they will ban you.

Comment: AdMob supports mixing with different ad networks to increase the fill rate. It is called "ad network mediation". Here is a list of all supported networks: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks

Comment: You are right... but still they don't allow all ad networks.